# Auto-update marker location on Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using MySQL and PHP to store the current location coordinates (latitude and longitude) after regular intervals. This is our code to add markers to the map from location coordinates fetched from the database.

I want to auto-update the marker's location on the map using updated coordinates from the database without refreshing the map. I have tried searching over the internet but couldn't find a solution that would help to update the coordinates in real time. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<div id="map"></div>
 <script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat , long),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var iconBase = 'XXXXXXX';
    var icons = {
      spot: {
        icon: 'XXXXXX'
      },
      0: {
        icon: iconBase + 'XXXXX'
      },
      1: {
        icon: iconBase + 'XXXX'
      },
    };

     function addMarker(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
        if(feature.type!="spot"){
         var content = '<font color="#636363"><h3><img src="http://XXXX"> '+feature.rto+'<br><img style="vertical-align: middle" src="http://XXXXXXX"> <a style="text-decoration:none" href="tel:+91'+feature.phone+'">'+feature.phone+'</a></h3></font>';  
     }
     else {
        var content = '<b>Address: </b>'+feature.address+'<br><b>Information: </b>XXXXXXXX';
     }
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,this);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
    }

    var features = [
      {
        <?php echo "position: new google.maps.LatLng(".$lat.", ".$long."),";
        echo "type: 'spot',
        address: '".$r['address']."'";
        ?>
      } 
      <?php
        $e = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "select distpref,radius from XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
        $er = $e['radius'];
        $dp = $e['distpref'];
      $sql = "SELECT *, ( $dp * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(" . $long . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance<$er";

      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo ", {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['latitude'].", ".$row['longitude']."),
        type: '".$row['type']."',
        phone: '".$row['phone']."'
        }";
      }
      ?>
    ];

    for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
      addMarker(feature);
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>`
```

Any alternative solutions will also be acceptable.

Comment: for update the coordinates in real time  you need  an ajax call of   php  module ...  you should split you code   .. in javascript part for rendering a map and an event based  ajax call to php server side code  for retrieving the new coords and in in the ajax success function manage the update of the maps with new coordinates ...   a long .. road to walk ..

Comment: @scaisEdge How do I do that? I can make the ajax call but how do I update the position of the markers?

Comment: in the ajax call you have a success function ... then with this function can call a simple  marker setposition eg:    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(your_new_lat, your_new_lng);     marker.setPosition(latlng);

Comment: @scaisEdge That seems to work if my map had only one marker, but here  I am having multiple markers, so how do I update a single marker?

Comment: if you have more mearker you should use a loop ,.. is  not so difftcult

Comment: @scaisEdge I have made the loop of Ajax to fetch current coordinates. But how do I update multiple markers on Google Maps considering those markers aren't tagged (so how do I identify them?)

Comment: you shoul store the marker in ana array of object and then  loop on it  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge In Google Directions, how do I update the origin marker using Ajax after every 0.5 second?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't live update multiple markers simultaneously. Instead, when the trip starts, I removed all markers and started to live update only one specific marker using Ajax and setInterval command.